# calling method in javascript, but error throws?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to call ajax method couple of places. So want to try to minimize the code by creating separate method for it. If use directly, it works perfect. but when I separate it won't work.

```
    data: columns[5],
    type: 'autocomplete',   
    options: { items: 100 },
    source: function (query, process) {    
            $.ajax({
            url: "/EditInitiatives.svc/GetLocationData?clientId=" + $value.val(),
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                      query: query
                   },
            success: function (response) {
                        process(response.d);
                     }
             });
          },
          strict: true
}
```

it doesn't work, if I call this way. It says `Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'query' is undefined`, how to fix it?

```
{
    data: columns[4],
    type: 'autocomplete', 
    options: { items: 100 },
    source: callAutoCompleteAjaxMethod(query, process, "/EditInitiatives.svc/GetLocationData?clientId=" + $value.val()),
    strict: true

 },

callAutoCompleteAjaxMethod = function (query, process, url) {
                 $.ajax({
                    url:url,
                    type: "GET",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {
                        query: query
                    },
                    success: function (response) {
                        process(response.d);
                    }
                });
            },
```

Comment: What part of the error don't you understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are **calling** the function instead of assigning it to the source property. And at this moment the variable `query` is not defined.

You have to assign a function, so that the plugin can call it later:

```
source: function (query, process) {
    callAutoCompleteAjaxMethod(
        query, 
        process, 
        "/EditInitiatives.svc/GetLocationData?clientId=" + $value.val()
    );
}
```

(I hope `$value` is defined somewhere)

Parenthesis ( `()` ) after a function reference always calls the function immediately. If you want to pass a reference to the function, you don't put parenthesis after it.

Answer (score 2):

You call

```
source: callAutoCompleteAjaxMethod(query, ...
```

But you never gave 'query' a value, give it a value and it will work.